# Is defining function pointer as a new type with a template type as an argument not possible in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

In C, I can do this.

```
typdef void(TRAVERSAL_CALLBACK*)(int a);
```

That would then allow me to pass function pointers to other functions as arguments, with that function having 1 argument of type int.

I've been working with templates, and currently, passing the function pointer to the method works like this:

```
void my_function(void(TRAVERSAL_CALLBACK*)(T &data));
```

Now, is it possible if I define a new type with argument of type T. I have tried but it has failed to compile.

```
typedef void(TRAVERSAL_CALLBACK*)(T &data);
```

I'm using C++11. Is this something that I have to accept as not possible, or is there an idomatic way to do this in C++11 that I am not aware of?

Comment: do you mean `function<int>` that will become `void(*)(int& data);` ?

Comment: @PiotrS. No i don't think so. I was hoping to be able to define a new function pointer type like I can do in C, but allow that new function pointer type to take arguments of `template<class T>`

Comment: Why the down-vote? I've done research, and have put effort into the question.

Comment: you want `template<class T>` to be part of what?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in C++11 it's possible, thanks to the "new" `using`:

```
template<typename T>
using TRAVERSAL_CALLBACK = void(*)(T &data);
```

Notice however that in C++ you'd probably just make the whole type of the callback a template, to allow the usage of other types of callable objects (functors, lambdas, ...).

Comment: Excellent. so what is `TRAVERSAL_CALLBACK` exactly? Is it a type?

Comment: `TRAVERSAL_CALLBACK<Type>` == `void(TRAVERSAL_CALLBACK*)(T&)`

Comment: agree: if you have function pointers in your C++ code, you most likely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, there is template type aliasing using the `using` statement, example shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T foo() {return 10;}

template <typename T>
using fptr = T (foo*)(void);
int main()
{
    fptr<int> x1 = foo<int>;
    fptr<double> x2 = foo<double>;
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

However, in your case you most likely don't need to go that far. If you define the type within the scope of the template, it should work fine:

```
template <typename T>
struct bar
{
  typedef T (*qiz)(void);

  void baz(qiz q)
  {
    std::cout << q << std::endl;
  }

};
```